# Cookies on server side not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, https

```
 static class CookiePathComparator implements Comparator<HttpCookie> {
public int compare(HttpCookie c1, HttpCookie c2) {
    if (c1 == c2) return 0;
    if (c1 == null) return -1;
    if (c2 == null) return 1;

    // path rule only applies to the cookies with same name
    if (!c1.getName().equals(c2.getName())) return 0;

    // those with more specific Path attributes precede those with less specific
    if (c1.getPath().startsWith(c2.getPath()))
        return -1;
    else if (c2.getPath().startsWith(c1.getPath()))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

}
```

I have problems with handling session on the server side. It always return that I'm not logged in (spring).

Question: What kind of information should I provide?

Answer (score 1):

See the difference between

```
object1 == object2
```

and

```
object1.equals(object2)
```

That is absolutely incorrect too

```
if (!c1.getName().equals(c2.getName())) return 0;
```

compare(Object obj1, Object obj2)
should return 0 when two objects are equal...